# Configure gradle-download-plugin unzip in kotlin

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

The documentation of the [gradle-download-task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task?tab=readme-ov-file#download-and-extract-a-zip-file) plugin shows an example of how to download and unzip a file.

```
task downloadZipFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task/archive/refs/tags/5.5.0.zip'
    dest layout.buildDirectory.file('5.5.0.zip')
}

task downloadAndUnzipFile(dependsOn: downloadZipFile, type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(downloadZipFile.dest)
    into layout.buildDirectory
}
```

As far as I know the first part will look like this in kotlin. Am I right?

```
task<Download>("downloadZipFile") {
    src("https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip")
    dest(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("gradle-dists"))
}
```

The second part, the unzipping of the file, confuses me. Usually I would convert it to kotlin in this way

```
task<Copy>("downloadAndUnzipFile") {
    from(zipTree(downloadZipFile.dest))
    into(layout.buildDirectory)
}
```

But what about the `dependsOn: downloadZipFile`. How is that converted to kotlin dsl?

Maybe someone can tell me how to read the documentation in order to get to the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the task function on the [`Project`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) returns a [`Task`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html) you can use a `val`

```
val downloadZipFile = task<Download>("downloadZipFile") {
    src("https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip")
    dest(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("gradle-dists"))
}

task<Copy>("downloadAndUnzipFile") {
    dependsOn(downloadZipFile)
    from(zipTree(downloadZipFile.dest))
    into(layout.buildDirectory)
}
```

or you can use the [`tasks` property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getTasks--) of the project and lookup the task,

```
task<Download>("downloadZipFile") {
    src("https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip")
    dest(project.layout.buildDirectory.dir("gradle-dists"))
}

task<Copy>("downloadAndUnzipFile") {
    dependsOn(tasks.getByName("downloadZipFile"))
    from(zipTree(downloadZipFile.dest))
    into(layout.buildDirectory)
}
```

I will prefer the first solution since you don't rely on variable names rather then strings. I guess the IDEs support a better rename refactoring.